# WAMP Server not working

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

Okay so a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409913/can-php-be-installed-on-a-local-machine), where you experts intro'd me to [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/presentation.php), which can basically execute PHP within a Windows XP environment.

So now I've got it installed, but the **tray icon forever shows YELLOW**, and when I visit any PHP page in my browser, it just shows me the PHP source!

Also, when I visit "http://localhost/" in IE7 it gives me a **404 Not Found**, FF3 just shows a **blank** page.

---

BTW I've tried "Restart All Services" and restarting my machine, but it still won't work.

Any ideas? Any of you had this problem and **solved it?** Please help me here, I'm desperate to execute PHP client-side and I'm just reverting to testing on-server for now!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Skype reserves port 80 for its incoming connection which conflicts with WAMP, so simply configure Skype to use another port by doing the following:

In Skype go to Tools|Options|Advanced|Connection uncheck the option --> Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections, that's it

For this change to take effect restart Skype and Restart all services on WAMP by doing the following:

Left-click WAMP tray icon > Restart All Services"

Now Wamp and Skype can co-exist together, hope this solves your problem!!

Comment: Thanks! I had been developing a project for 2 weeks that I needed to show my supervisor in 12 hours and for the 1st time my WAMP server stopped working---stressing---this solution was a big relief!

Comment: Thanks to all I have got the same error on wamp but the problem with IIS services. And solved with just to change the Listen 80 to Listen 8080 in httpd.conf

Comment: Right Answer. Skype port conflicts with WAMP specially when Skype reinstalled and we don't set its port by 443. I also tried in httpd.conf by changing Listen 80 to 8080 but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 9):

Got it! Under the **WAMP tray icon**, left-click context menu > **Apache** > **Service** > **Test Port 80**, it said :

> "Your **port 80 is actually used** by - Info not available, Must be **Skype**"

Well, so **off** goes Skype, **WAMP > Restart All Services**, and [Localhost](http://localhost/) shows ["WAMP5 Homepage":](http://www.wampserver.com/en/data/image_accueil_wamp.gif)

[image: Localhost WAMP CP]
<sub>(source: [wampserver.com](http://www.wampserver.com/en/data/image_accueil_wamp.gif))</sub>

And, [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) works, **PHP scripts** execute too. **Wow!**

So now I can dubug in the proper fashion! Thank you [StackOverflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409913/can-php-be-installed-on-a-local-machine)

Comment: ah yes - skype on port 80 had me puzzled a couple of times as well - nice that WAMP provides a hint! Good to hear it works now.

Comment: Take it a step further for easy access to php lint. Put C:\wamp\bin\php\ (or whatever the path to the directory with your php.exe file is) in your user PATH variable and then you have PHP CLI (command line interface) and you can open cmd.exe and php -l file.php and it'll tell you where the syntax errors are.  You can also execute one liners very quickly with php -r "code;"

Answer (score 8):

try this one, i had the same problem and this helped me:

1. Wamp Server icon => Appache => Service => Install Service
2. Wamp Server icon => Appache => Service => Start/Resume Service
3. Wamp Server icon => MySql => Service => Install Service
4. Wamp Server icon => MySql => Service => Start/Resume Service

Answer (score 6):

just go to wamp>bin>apache>apache 2.2.17>conf>httpd.conf (file)
change `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`
save the file 
n restart the services
this time type http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 3):

Glad you got it sorted - Skype is notorious for that.

If you want to use Skype and WAMP together, you can edit your httpd.conf file - change the 'listen' value from 80 to something else and restart all services.

Answer (score 3):

Teamviewer can cause this too.

Answer (score 1):

you can start Skype up after wamp is online or change Skypes port not to use 80

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand on what some of the other folks have contributed here - as Skype is not always the culprit.

You can also check exactly which process is hogging your port 80 by running this from a command prompt:

`netstat -ao`

This will list all processes using ports with their PID. You can correlate those to processes in Task Manager, and take appropriate action from there. The bottom line is - you're looking for what's hogging port 80 and/or 443 (if you're connecting over SSL), as that is the default browser port.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I have opened the httpd.conf file I have found that I have tow Listen statement as following:

```
Listen 80
Listen 169.254.96.77:80
```

and when I have commented the second line (adding '#' at beginning of the line) I restarted all wamp services (left click of wamp icon in the task bar), the wamp icon became green!

Hope this help other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case the above still dont help as it was with me, follow these steps:

- Change your apache port (from httpd.conf) to something else, say 8056, at the two places where port 80 occurs in the file
- Then change your browser proxy appropriately. i.e the proxy to "localhost" and the port to your "8056".
- Save the file and restart Wamp Services
- Launch localhost in your browser

Hope it works! A better approach is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem happens because of conflict between apachi servers, or ports, or duplicate of wamp installation

So to fix that:

First of all if you are using SKYPE try to change the port by opening Skype, then:

- Tools menu
- Options
- Advanced Options
- Connections
- Then uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 ......"
- save
- restart Skype

second if the problem still exists try to find if you are using - or was using - other Apache server (for example XAMPP server), if so try to remove it and after removing it, go to regedit by:

- press on keyboard the "windows" button + "r" button, this will open the Run command
- type "regedit" (without "")
- open Edit menu then Find (you can press "CTRL" button + "F" button)
- search for anything belongs to the other apache server and delete it (You should be careful while you are doing this step)

Answer (score 0):

**In skype:**

Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".

This should help.