# Can't connect to my server when I put in my IP in Java

Tags: java, client, client-server

Okay so I'm trying to learn Java client/server stuff, and am going through the tutorial code as follows. When I change "localhost" to my ip it stops working though. Please help.

Edit: "127.0.0.1" seems to work too, but not my real IP.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995 - 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Sun Microsystems nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();

        outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
             out.println(outputLine);
             if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}


/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995 - 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Sun Microsystems nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class KnockKnockClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;
        String fromUser;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
            if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                break;

            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
        if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);
        }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at KnockKnockClient.main(KnockKnockClient.java:43)
```

Comment: When you say "stops working", what do you mean exactly? Does an Exception get thrown? If so, can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Change that useless error message to print the actual exception. I complained to Sun years ago about using those stupid error messages in their tutorials. I think they finally fixed some of them. Apparently not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require wild guesses, but let's see. If you are running this in Windows 7, note that your "localhost" name may be bound to your computer's IPV6 address instead of IPV4. The fact that you can still access it using 127.0.0.1 points to that.

See [this question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813347/http-localhost-not-working-on-windows-7-whats-the-problem)

I should add: try "ping localhost" to find out what IP address it's bound to. And, if you can, pass "0.0.0.0" as the adapter to bind to in the server program, that will force it to IPV4.

Comment: ping ip is returning 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Check the hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

You should have an entry something like

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

In some cases, localhost can be set to another value and this will cause incorrect operation.

```
netstat -a -n | find "LIST"
```

in a cmd box will show all listening programs and their ports.  If the port is in use then you will see it listed here.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check your computer's firewall settings. It might let localhost traffic through but block the other IPs

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly a couple of things going on here:

1. Most probable, Your `ServerSocket` gets bound to a local IP address (e.g. `0.0.0.0`) and ServerSocket binds to the port address there; and wouldn't respond to any requests coming from an IP address.  Try `new ServerSocket(4444, 50, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { YOU IP ADDRESS })`.
2. You could have a firewall blocking requests and such.

Comment: I'm still new at this client server thing, so where do I put this? The client or the server?

Comment: What format is YOUR IP ADDRESS in? I tried just the address, and it didn't work, I tried XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX and it didn't work eather.

Comment: Okay I got it to work, but now I'm getting this:
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at KnockKnockServer.main(KnockKnockServer.java:40)

Comment: you express the ip address as byte array.  You can also use `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")`

Comment: (1) is nonsense. A socket bound to 0.0.0.0 will respond to incoming requests via *any* local IP address.