# Why won't localhost work with RoR and Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, localhost

I'm new to both ruby on rails and Windows 7.  I got windows 7 for christmas and used a border's gift card to buy a book on Ruby on rails.  My point is, I don't know if it's W7 that's causing the problem, or not.  I checked my host file and that checks out.  I've tried several ports including 8080, 80, and 3000.

Localhost is just not working.

Comment: Check for a solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813347/http-localhost-not-working-on-windows-7-whats-the-problem

Comment: Is http://127.0.0.1:3000 working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Notepad as an Administrator then open this file to see if you have changed the type of file to all:

`C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

After you load this file delete "#" where you have writen `# 127.0.0.1 localhost`.
Then save and should work fine

Let me know if this works :)