# Wampserver 2.1 gives orange icon after install on Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-7, wamp

I just installed Wampserver 2.1 on my windows 7 64bit computer and the icon that should turn green, turns orange, saying that the server is not ready.

The result is that on opening the browser on http://localhost/ it just timed out.

anybody an idea, I tried google on this, but without any correct result.

The apache error log says this:

```
[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4320

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Child process is running

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Acquired the start mutex.

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Starting 64 worker threads.

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Starting thread to listen on port 80.

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4320

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Child process is running

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Acquired the start mutex.

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Starting 64 worker threads.

[Fri Mar 11 14:40:58 2011] [notice] Child 4320: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

so no mayor issues in my opinion.

versions running are:
apache 2.2.17
php 5.3.4
mysql 5.1.53

If I use the service to test port 80, he does that ok, saying to me this:

Port 80 is actually being used by: Server: Apache/2.2.17 (win32) php/5.3.4

**update**: It still isn't solved after some months and Skype is not even installed and never has been installed on the computer.

Answer (score 29):

It is probably your Skype giving you a hard time. Try configuring your Skype this way:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection -> Unchecking the 'Use port 80...'

I had the same problem and it worked for me.

Comment: or Teamviewer. Thats what it was for me

Comment: Thanks @GabrielFair. I think oDesk Teamviewer app is the one causing it.

Answer (score 29):

I have had the same issues on Windows 7, orange WAMP icon and when the mouse is on the WAMP icon, it shows the server is online, but I cannot connect to the server.
Found out nothing running on port 80, I do not have skype and my  hosts file is correct.

What worked for me is described below.

When I left click on the WAMP icon Apache -> Service, I saw that the start/stop service was grayed out.

So, I clicked on "Install service"  Apache -> Service -> Install Service.

This did the trick

Comment: I had to install visual C++ like the wamp web site told me to. Once I did that, "Install Service" did the trick.

Comment: Good answer.  Worked for me but I also disabled http.sys per this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813347) thread prior to doing this.

Comment: I found message saying "the program can't start because msvcr100.dll is missing from your computer" when I was trying this. then I installed patch as this artical says http://www.faqforge.com/windows/fix-the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-on-windows/ it worked after restart. Thanks

Comment: This fixed it for me too once the Visual C++ redistributable was installed.

Answer (score 4):

check the Apache port being used by your wamp at "http.conf" . Try changing the port to a number above 1024 and than restart apache. Than try to access the Apache server using a url like http://localhost:$PORT_NUMBER_HERE . If it works is because your user does not have permission to open a socket below 1024. This is common in unix environments but I am not a windows user to know if it has the same restrictions. Have a try.

You might also check the windows firewall and give access to the port being used, if the firewall is blocking it.

regards.

Comment: The conf file is probably under: wamp\Apache2\conf

Comment: That didn't do the trick. If I use the service to test port 80, he does that ok, saying to me this: Port 80 is actually being used by: Server: Apache/2.2.17 (win32) php/5.3.4

Comment: So check the firewall. Also test using telnet command from console: "telnet localhost 80"

Comment: do you have skype installed? I have seen this problem with skype and wamp running at the same time.

Comment: nope skype isn't installed, that's the argument you read all over the internet :-)

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this for hours on end on different machines. Often one solution did not work on the next machine. This is what I, by trial and error, found out worked like a charm every time.

Installed WAMP on win7 POS

1. Add MSVCR100.dll to System32
2. Install VB 2008
3. Install WAMP
4. Disable World wide web publishing service in Services
5. Start WAMP as administrator.

Finished. No need to edit httpd.conf, no need to edit hosts-file and no need to disable IIS.

A total install of WAMP following these steps take well under ten minutes.
Hope it does the trick for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check each service individually.  MySQL uses port 3360 so that might be blocked as well.

On a personal note, I've been finding WAMP a problem after version 2.0i, so I switched to a Linux VM or even another computer running linux for my PHP development.

Try [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org) since you can install that onto a USB drive so you can keep the "WAMP" with you.

Answer (score 2):

Check your hosts file. It should be located @ */windows/system 32/drivers/etc/*

Edit the file in notepad or something similar and look for two lines that read something like

*# 127.0.0.1 localhost and # ::1 localhost*

Remove the # from the beginning of each line, save the file (make sure there is no file extension when you do) and then restart WAMP.

This should work, at least it did for me, but there are various other programs that can conflict with WAMP like Skype.

Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

I use Wampserver 2.2. I had the same problem, icon would just stay orange... Here's what I found out : If you click on the

> Wamp Tray Icon > Apache > Service > Test Port 80

Well that showed me what was already using port 80: `Server : Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`, which is not what I wanted... So I did like suggested above and changed the value of Listen 80 in http.conf to Listen 81. Stopped and restarted and it works.

Comment: Here's another resource that helped me track down what was blocking port 80: http://www.devlog.nl/apache-on-port-80-blocked-by-microsoft-httpapi2-0/

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with an orange wamp due to that IIS and/or the Web Deployment Agent Service used when developing web applications in Visual Studio was blocking port 80. When I stopped these two services wamp started just fine with a beautiful green icon :)

Run these two commads from the commandline as administrator to stop the services

```
iisreset /stop
net stop msdepsvc
```

Comment: How to recover and or change it back to the original state? (Just incase I mess things up)  Just change the word "stop" into "start"?

Comment: Yes, just change stop to start

Comment: iisreset isn't recognized as an intern or extern task, program or batchfile.

Comment: Try NET STOP W3SVC instead of iisreset /stop

Comment: Please explain to me why I should use NET STOP W3SVC instead of iisreset /stop

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and after reading this post, I found that here's what you need to do, if you're running both Wamp and Skype at the same time, to avoid issues. **MAKE SURE YOU OPEN YOUR WAMP SERVER FIRST, THEN OPEN SKYPE**. That eliminated the problem, I was able to connect to the WAMP server with no problem, and the icon was green :).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today. I changed the #listen from 80 to 86 and it still did not work.

I found this on the wampserver forum:

- apache uses 80 (I changed this to 86 using the methods in other answers here)
- mysql uses 3306
- edit the my.ini in mysql folder
- change 3306 to 3307
- written 3 times in the file
- save and restart wamp.

After this my icon finally turned green. However when I went to localhost it still said not found. This is because you need to append the new port you are using to localhost - ie localhost:86

Answer (score 0):

I just right clicked on Wamp and changed http.conf . the listening port was 80 and I changed it to 2000

```
Listen 2000
```

and everything worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I just unchecked using port 80 from Skype advance settings and it start working fine.

Before that I had changed the MySQL port 3306 to 3307 from the MySQL *my.ini* file

Answer (score 0):

```
C:/wamp/alias
```

and look your alias maybe you change DISK `D:\` to `K:\`

```
"Alias /virtualram/ "D:/virtualram/".
```

Do not change port *80* to *8080*!

gl

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling the Microsoft Visual C++ to 64 bits (it was 32 bits, don't know why).

More info:

http://www.faqforge.com/windows/fix-the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by

```
1 - # 127.0.0.1 localhost and # ::1 localhost and uncommenting these
lines in host file

2 - Inside MySql - my.ini file changing port 3306 to 3307 at three
places
```

Thanks Guys !

Answer (score 0):

Fix for Windows 7 PC - Open ISS Manager -> Stop the Service from the right bar.

And select restart all service on Wamp CP.

Worked for me ;)