# WAMP icon is orange - tried skype and install apache service fixes

Tags: php, apache, wamp

My WAMP icon is randomly orange. I think the only change I've made to this computer is installing Windows Visual Studio Express.

I've followed this on solving it... including changing Skype port and installing apache service fixes: [Wampserver 2.1 gives orange icon after install on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273693/wampserver-2-1-gives-orange-icon-after-install-on-windows-7)

It gives the following... I have no idea what `Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0` is... but more importantly why WAMP isn't running on this port:

[image]

Other things I've tried:

- in System32/drivers/hosts file, change `::1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 localhost`, but it was already set the correct way: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,70321
- Look in WAMP apache error log: Nothing

Any other suggestions?

---

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: This one bit me as well - see http://www.ferolen.com/blog/microsoft-httpapi2-0-use-port-80-cannot-start-wamp-apache/ for more detail.  You need to deactivate the `Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc)` service

Comment: Okay I did that, but Web Deployment Agent Service started itself on system reboot... and I tried manually starting apache from `Admin tools -> Services` and it threw the error above.

Comment: @fvu Since it seems correlated to my MS Visual Studio install, I  read this line `solutions mentioned about turning off Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)` and thought of uninstalling it. You think that would help?

Comment: @fvu whoops. Had to go to `msconfig` and turn off the auto start for `Web Deployment Agent Service` and, on restart, the WAMP platform boots up. Thanks!

Comment: @fvu please post as answer, including changing auto start in `msconfig`, and I'll accept it! Thanks again

Comment: I just checked, seems like I didn't have to do anything in MSConfig, could be related to the version/edition of MsDepSvc??  Mine came with WebMatrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one bit me as well - see http://www.ferolen.com/blog/microsoft-httpapi2-0-use-port-80-cannot-start-wamp-apache/ for more detail. You need to deactivate the "Web Deployment Agent Service" (MsDepSvc) service.

Several references to that service here on SO as well, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602502/why-does-the-web-deploy-agent-service-listen-on-port-80-and-8172), it doesn't seem useful at all when you're using a non IIS stack.