# Java, client-server communication

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, socket.io

I have a little server.jar, which listen to GET and END command on port 10000.

My client code is :

```
package communication;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {

            Socket socket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            socket = new Socket("localhost",10000);
            System.out.println("SOCKET = " + socket);
            System.out.print(socket.getInetAddress() + "\n");
            System.out.print(socket.getInputStream() + "\n");
            System.out.println(socket.isConnected() + "\n");

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

            in = new BufferedReader(new 
                            InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String str = "GET";
            out.println(str);   
            String reponse = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(socket.isConnected() + "\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    out.println(str);          // envoi d'un message
                    reponse = in.readLine();      // lecture de la reponse
                    System.out.println("Forme recue: " + reponse);
            }
            System.out.println("END");     // message de terminaison
            out.println("END") ;
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
}
}
```

I know this code works, because it runs on one of my computers. However, I can't make it run on another one. Configurations on both are : Windows 7 64, JRE 6, Eclipse.

My server.jar application opens a little GUi that lets me know wether the communication is open or not, which is never the case on the computer that btw get stuck on the readLine() line.

I tried to turn off Windows firewall, antivirus... nothing worked.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

thanks!!

Comment: We need more information to help you. What errors do you get? whats the behavior etc.

Comment: I don't get any error, the program just get stuck at the line String reponse = in.readLine(); In my case it actually is a lack of behavior that bothers me ;)

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? Why don't you have any SocketServer if you want a server-client communication?

Comment: The "server" is just a little executable jar. I launch it, then it listens on port 10000, waiting for GET and END commands. I tested it with Telnet, worked #1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im staring at the `localhost` string, and have a hunch that could be the problem.

In an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813347/http-localhost-not-working-on-windows-7-whats-the-problem), there could be something with the `:: localhost` that needs to be commented, and also hardcoding the *localhost* as *127.0.0.1* in your *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* file.

By hardcoding the `localhost` with a specific IP address, the server will listen to the same `localhost` as the one your client program tries to connect to.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that tonight, I'll keep you posted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try - add an out.flush() right after your out.println.

Comment: I just tried that, nothing, still stuck at readLine(). And I strongly doubt that I have to change the code, since it works on another computer... that must be something else... I guess :)

Comment: One thing I didn't mention, System.out.println(socket.isConnected() + "\n"); return true.

Comment: You're right, you are setting autoflush on. Are you sure the server is receiving your request and printing a response? Just for the fun of it, can you try closing the output stream after each println (then open a new one before each println).

Comment: On the client side, the connection seems to be open; however, on the server side, i.e. on my server.jar GUI, no connection appears. With Putty-telnet, on the very same port (10000), life pops up on the server's GUI, and I can send manually GET and END command and get what I want from the server in return...

Comment: Is your server side using a ServerSocket?