# How to show sphinx search result with php?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I installed sphinx search on localhost (wamp).
I want to show results for example in one simple html table. I tried to connect with php to sphinx search, I think it done it, but when I printed the result it was 0.... but that was not true. 
I do not really understand that in query part I need to put the word what I want to search?
I tried search in command windows, it is good working, just I do not know how to show it on web page.
And I want to use mysql.
So my PHP looks like this:

```
require ( "sphinx/api/sphinxapi.php" );
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9306);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$s->setMaxQueryTime(3);

$result = $s->query("test");

var_dump($result);
```

Here is my mini conf file:

```
source src1
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db          = test
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
        FROM documents

    sql_attr_uint       = group_id
    sql_attr_timestamp  = date_added

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id
}


index test1
{
    source          = src1
    path            = C:/wamp/www/sphinx/data/test1
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type        = sbcs
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = C:/wamp/www/sphinx/log/searchd.log
    query_log       = C:/wamp/www/sphinx/log/query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file        = C:/wamp/www/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = C:/wamp/www/sphinx/data
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection and a query might look like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect ( '127.0.0.1:9306', '', '' );
$db_selected = mysql_select_db ( 'main', $link );
```

and then normally mysql queries (as you would do them normally)

```
$sql = "select * from main WHERE MATCH('$queryterm') order by date desc LIMIT 0,50";
$result = mysql_query ( $sql );
```

Or you can retrieve some meta info if you want(see Sphinx document for the meta)

```
$metainfo = mysql_query('SHOW META');
while ( $meta = mysql_fetch_array ( $metainfo ) ) {
        $srchmeta[]=$meta;
//or whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! I tried your first variation.... an I done: "var_dump($db_selected);" but it returned just "bool(true)". How to show matches in table?

Comment: That means that the connection is successful. Try the rest.

Comment: Thnak you. Another one stuff, In windows wamp, so when i add new stuff in database the search do not see it. How to do automaticly to searc in new rows too?

Comment: Resources have to be "indexed" to be shown in the Sphinx. In linux there is the "indexer" who deals with indexing. I am not aware of the windows version but you have to locate the indexer and put it in a cron tab. The docs are here for the indexer: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.1.1/ref-indexer.html and here for the live indexing overview: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.1.1/live-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

> $s->setServer("localhost", 9306);

Thats the mysql protocol port - sphinxQL.

In your config file you have sphinx listening on 9312 with the sphinxAPI protocol. So change your setServer line to use 9312

Comment: changing from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" was important to getting sphinx working on windows / wamp for me, so I wouldn't advise using "localhost"

Comment: Yes, can sometimes be issues with 'localhost' - even if just slower because it involves a DNS lookup. But that DNS lookup can fail too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/813437/65548