# Not able to open website on localhost

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I am developing a website on localhost wamp using Wordpress. Today when I tried to open my wordpress account it was displaying an error `"This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"`,also I am not able to see any of my webpages.

I tried using IP address instead and tried to open on other browser like firefox,IE also (initially, I was working on chrome) but nothing worked.

Can anyone please suggest some solution to this??

Comment: is your wamp server working ?  localhost/phpmyadmin ? or localhost/anyotherproject ..

Comment: No it's not working too. Also wamp symbol changed to orange. I guess reason behind this is my apache server not working.I tried to change port number in httpd.conf file and also tried to install services but nothing worked. When I tested port 80 it shows "your port 80 is not actually used"

Answer (score 0):

Skype reserves port 80 for its incoming connection which conflicts with WAMP, so simply configure Skype to use another port by doing the following:

In Skype go to Tools|Options|Advanced|Connection uncheck the option --> Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections, that's it

For this change to take effect restart Skype and Restart all services on WAMP by doing the following:

Left-click WAMP tray icon > Restart All Services"

Now Wamp and Skype can co-exist together, hope this solves your problem!!

Have a look at this post:[WAMP Server not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410391/wamp-server-not-working)

Comment: I tried all the things given in post..but nothing worked for me..is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: you can try this: Click on wamp icon > Apache > Services > Install Service.