# Myphp.php editor does not run with browser

Tags: php, browser

i cant open .php item with browser
here is my sample code :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<html>
<head>
<title>Php Deneme Studyoları</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Php Deneme Studyoları</h1>
<?php
echo "I love making web sites"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

> when i want to myphp.php item run with my browser ; it can not run and
>   i see same item is downloaded by the browser this screen on browser is
>   seen.

How can i solve this error?
as seen in picture php item does not open ?
it seems like it is donwloaded

[My problem on linux forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=194308)

Comment: Are you trying to run this from your own computer or hosted site? If local, is a web server and PHP installed and running properly? Are you accessing using `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`? There's a difference.

Comment: Do you have the webserver on system at all?

Comment: i start localhost but i cant  start http://localhost/file.php when i try it file.php is downloaded by browser all the  nothing more .

Comment: i set up all LAMP but i still get thie error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP be installed on a local machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409913/can-php-be-installed-on-a-local-machine)

Comment: Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3  i get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the ";" at the end of "echo "I love making web sites" ". Trythat

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If anything, they'd be getting a parse error. Good catch, but no cigar. Re-read the question again.

Comment: I thought he already had the localhost server up ans runing

Comment: No, officially you don't need that right before the closing `?>`. Don't ask why...

Comment: @jeroen  *"Don't ask why"* - Just like K.A.O.S. eh? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Never got that really, remove the `?>` at the end of your file and all of a sudden you have a parse error. Keeps things interesting though.

Comment: @jeroen *Strangely enough*. Who came up with that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Don't ask that either ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I won't. I'm afraid Siegfried may be watching. *Starker!!!!*

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a server-side language and you cannot just open it in your browser by dragging it in. It needs to be parsed by a server, which could be your own machine.

To do this PHP and Apache (or some other webserver) needs to be installed on your machine. Then in the htdocs/www root you can put your php file and generally open it by going to http://localhost/myphp.php

If you cannot get it to work, find a beginner's guide for creating your first php project.